# Rails/React App Signup throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, fetch-api, internal-server-error

I'm trying to get user data to save to my Rails DB for user info through a sign up form on a React front end. I've got my route and controller written properly (at least I think) and the fetch request below but I keep getting a 500 internal error through on submit. Please let me know what I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated!

My route:

resources :users, only: [:show, :create]

My create action in UsersController:

```
  def create
    user = User.create!(user_params)
      if user.valid?
        session[:user_id] = user.id # remembering who our user is 
        render json: user, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {error: user.errors.messages}
      end
  end
```

and lastly my fetch request from the Signup.js component on the React frontend, where I'm getting the error on the line that has 'fetch'

```
fetch(`/users`,{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body:JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(res => {
        if(res.ok){
            res.json().then(user => {
                history.push(`/users/${user.id}`)
            })
```

Comment: Try using a debugger to make sure User.create!(user_params) is actually working without raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

This might only be part of your problem, but first creating, then asking for validity is backwards.

Do something like this instead:

```rb
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save # <-- will return false if the save fails
      user.reload
      session[:user_id] = user.id # remembering who our user is 
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {error: user.errors.messages}
    end
end
```

If you really want to check validity explicitly:

```rb
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.valid? # <-- will check validity
      user.save
      user.reload
      session[:user_id] = user.id # remembering who our user is 
      render json: user, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {error: user.errors.messages}
    end
end
```

My guess is your error might be coming from the fact that your `user` variable doesn't actually have an ID yet. You need to save the record, then refresh it to get an ID.